# How to secure a spring webapp using a LDAP server

Tags: spring, web-applications, spring-security, ldap, spring-ldap

I have a webapp which is created using Spring and Maven. Which means it does not have a web.xml. I need to know how to secure this web app using spring security. Basically I need to connect to a LDAP server and cross check the credentials against it. I am a complete beginner in this scenario. So please help.  Any guidelines or tutorials are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best starting point would be the excellent [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/). There's also a getting started guide [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/). If you have specific problems or questions about details in the documentation or the guide, feel free to ask again :)

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply but the reference documentation link does not work

Comment: Sorry, fixed the link.